# What are partial differential equations with fast reaction terms?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, applied-mathematics

I know $u_t(t,x)=\Delta u^m(t,x),\;\; (t,x)\in (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ is the fast-diffusion equation when $m\in (0,1).$

But how are PDEs with fast reaction terms defined in general? I also wish to know about some real-world problems where such PDEs find possible applications.

If you could also suggest in your answer any website or article where I can read more about them, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The nonlinear diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)=\nabla(u^{\gamma-1}\nabla u)+f(x)$$
with $\gamma<1$ describes a porous medium with capillary-driven flow. One distinguishes fast diffusion for $0<\gamma<1$ and superfast diffusion for $\gamma<0$.

Experiments are described in [Superfast non-linear diffusion: Capillary transport in particulate porous media](https://centaur.reading.ac.uk/29798/1/prl-2012.pdf). (See also [Capillary transport in low saturated sands](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.04710.pdf).) A real-world application is in chromatography for medical diagnosis (see [Capillary transport in paper porous materials at low saturation levels: normal, fast or superfast](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.12419.pdf)).